# How to register a mock object in Service Container testing

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

I need to register a object to the service container. 
I tried with the following code but I get

> Error Call to undefined method ::process()

```php
$o = $this->instance(Service::class, Mockery::mock(Service::class, function ($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once()->andReturn(10);
}));

$this->app->instance(Service::class, $o);

dd((new Service())->process());
```

Comment: you are directly creating a new instance of `Service` and calilng `process` on it ... you are not even involving that mock or the container

Comment: Did my answer help your problem or is there still errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly for mocking an object, this should suffice. The middle step is not required.

```
$this->instance(Service::class, Mockery::mock(Service::class, function ($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive('process')->once()->andReturn(10);
}));
```

For your mock to load, you have to get it out through the container, you have recently bound it with the container. There are many ways of doing this, `$this->app->instance()`, `app()`, `resolve()` etc.

```
dd($this->app->instance(Service::class)->process());
```